# Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program when binding data to listbox in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am binding data to a listbox ,Every item of list is containing a large amount of text , but a the time of UI visualization getting above exception...and i try to find solutions regarding lazy loading with listbox but not getting proper solution ....could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post this as a more complete explanation of exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: I think the text that you trying to load is to large. Can you truncate the text? And do something like "bla bla (view full)"?

Comment: "Every item of list is containing a large amount of text" - how large is large? As long as a long piece of string?

Comment: yes it is a large string...actually this string comes by parsing html file and these html files having 20kb to 50 kb weightage

Comment: maximum length for a string is between 20,000 to 40,000

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the size of data that you are trying to bind on your control.
If it is very heavy You should divide your data into sections and then try to display it.

Also try to set this property on Your Control. Some time this problem occurs due to `Recycling` nature of UI Element. So try this if it works.

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
```

This works well in case of LongListSelector and ListBox if you are using that.